# library interposition with dlsym

Tags: php, mysql, libc, dlsym

I'm writing an interposition library to track the usage of some library functions in libc, such as open(), close(), connect(), etc. It works generally well on most of the applications. However, when I try it with PHP, using PHP's MySQL module in particular, none of the function calls to libc inside this module is been tracked (so no connect(), no socket(), etc.). 'strace' told me that the system calls socket(), connect(), etc., took place. Running 'file' on the module and libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 said that they are all dynamically linked. So it shouldn't be a problem caused by static linkage. What might be the problem?

I'm using Fedora 11 64-bit version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that it was not caused by static linkage. In fact, PHP is dynamically linked to other libraries. The problem relies in the way PHP loads extensions.

PHP loads extensions by calling dlopen() with flags RTLD_LAZY, which means that the symbol will only be resolved when the reference is executed. This bypasses the interposition specified by LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the library may be invoking system calls directly for some reason. In this case you'd need to use `strace` (or `ptrace()` in your own program) to track this usage.

Comment: by reading the source code of the mysql client library, it looks like that it's calling connect(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above that these libraries may be bypassing the calls to open(), write(), etc in libc.. In other words, those libraries may be  calling the system calls directly using assembly and not using the libc interface.. although it is not all that common to see applications using the syscalls directly, it is not unheard of.. 
If that's the case, that's why you would not see any interception in your library interposition experiment.. You have two ways then, the quick one through strace and the more complex one in building a kernel module that will intercept these calls at the kernel level and reporting to whatever framework you are building..
Have fun..
ErnestoB